# Creating hover and current page states with sibling elements

Tags: jquery, hover, parent-child, siblings, current-page

I have animated nav buttons and can actually set everything with css with the exception of one element. An arrow. Here's the actual live page.

http://sclarkstudio.com/testing/mm/index.htm

I'm trying to make the arrow visible and static on the current page. I have a hover script that animates the arrow when the class is set to .arrow and it's static and visible when the class is set to .currenta.

```
<body id="@@id@@"> <!-- in this case "home" -->

<nav class="sidebar1">
<ul class="navbox">
    <li class="navBtn">
        <div class="slider on"></div>
        <a id="BtnText" class="navButton home"href="index.htm">Home</a>
        <div id="arrow" class="arrow"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="navBtn">
        <div class="slider on"></div>
        <a id="BtnText" class="navButton news"href="news.htm">News</a>
        <div id="arrow" class="arrow"></div>

and so on...



 </ul>
</nav>
```

The script that I'm trying to write just needs to change the class of the arrow div to ".currenta"

```
var bodyID = $("body").attr("id");
var url = window.location;

$(function() {

$('nav ul li a #BtnText').each(function(){
var myHref = $(this).attr('href');
if( url == myHref) {
    $(this).closest('div','#arrow').css('currenta');
} 
});
});
```

I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure this one out and not the best coder.

Answer (score 0):

First :  ID's should be unique.  It will only grab the first element it finds with that ID

Second : To add a class use [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Third : `window.location` will never == your `href` so the code will never run.  You want to check if it contains your href by using `indexOf`

Fourth: You can just grab the elements with their class name.

```
$('.arrow').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     if(window.location.indexOf($this.siblings('a.navButton').attr('href')) > -1){  //
         $this.removeClass('arrow').addClass('currenta');  
         // I think you wanted to remove the arrow class.. if not just remove it
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9x9uF/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have duplicate `id`s in your page `(BtnText and arrow)` exists more than once, change them to `class` because `id` must be unique. So your html should be like something like following

```
<nav class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="navbox">
        <li class="navBtn">
            <div class="slider on"></div>
            <a class="BtnText" class="navButton home" href="index.htm">Home</a>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="navBtn">
            <div class="slider on"></div>
            <a class="BtnText" class="navButton news" href="news.htm">News</a>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JS**

```
var url = window.location;
$(function() {
    $('nav ul li a.BtnText').each(function(){
        var myHref = $(this).attr('href');
        if(url.match(myHref)) { // use match
            $(this).next('div.arrow')
            .removeClass('arrow').addClass('currenta'); // use removeClass and addClass
        } 
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/fmLBe/2/).

**Update:**

Remember that after removing the class `arrow` you'll lose all styles associated with this class so you may just use `addClass` without removing the class `arrow` using `removeClass`. So, in that case

```
$(this).next('div.arrow').removeClass('arrow').addClass('currenta');
```

should be

```
$(this).next('div.arrow').addClass('currenta');
```

Comment: AWWWWWSOME! thanks for the feedback. I have a really hard time visualizing the code. I still had to tweak it. I added a var that gave me the page file name.

    var file = location.pathname.substr(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1,location.pathname.length);

and then added then tweaked the script from Sheikh.

    $(function() {
    $('nav ul li a.BtnText').each(function(){
        var myHref = $(this).attr('href');
        if( file == myHref) {
            $(this).next('div.arrow').removeClass('arrow').addClass('currenta');
        } 
    });
    });


Thanks so much.